# ApplicationBar Animation

Tags: windows-phone-7

I try to create my own application bar in my app based on StackPanel. Standart ApplicationBar could not contain in itself standart rectangle buttons and textblocks, but I want to use it. And I have a question about animation of my ApplicationBar (StackPanel). How to create an animation effect, when ApplicationBar smoothly shows from the bottom of screen and ApplicationBar Buttons "jumps" in ApplicationBar. Has anybody done that?
Also when tapping an ApplicationBar Button, is this a Tilt Effect?

Excuse my English, I'm from Russia, i used a translator.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use title effect to show the animation while tapping the ApplicationBar button. but you will have to use other animation to show the ApplicationBar appearing from bottom.

- http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/tag?name=animation
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Video/ff849718